# Scheduler called asyncronously RTOS and time measuring

Tags: asynchronous, operating-system, rtos, freertos, isr

In order to shorten follow up latency I am forcing task scheduler to run form ISR. By doing so I found that those tasks that are blocked are sooner woken up. That is because scheduler tick counter was incremented not only by tick timer but form ISR as well.

Is there any other method to block task for exact amount of time even though scheduler is being called asynchronously without relaying on other hardware such as timers?

Comment: You need to give more information. What do you mean by an exact amount of time? Do you mean 5ms +- 1ns for example? Do you mean you want a task to run every x seconds with a given tolerance, or actually block for a x seconds with a given tolerance?

Comment: In most RTOS an ISR that makes scheduling calls has an prologue and epilogue (enter/exit ISR calls/macros) that cause the scheduler to run immediately on exit from the interrupt context.  Invoking the scheduler arbitrarily seems like a bad idea.  If multiple nested interrupts occur and more then one scheduling function is called  you may end up running a lower priority take than required and will make the ISR execution time non-deterministic.  You are rather second guessing the RTOS design - I am no fan of FreeRTOS, but if you don't like its way of scheduling, choose something better.

Comment: It seems that you may be running the tick-handler rather then just the scheduler.  The scheduler should run on exit from interrupt without you "forcing" it (which is fundamentally a bad idea), but you have to implement your ISR according to the specific RTOS guidelines for your target.

Comment: If you were to specify your target processor/architecture, it would be possible to post an answer.